# invalid_clientId - client_id should be sent - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am getting this error in my Spring Boot batch application

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_clientId] client_id should be sent
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_clientId] client_id should be sent
Application.yml:

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          myserver:
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: **************
            client-secret: **************
        provider:
          myserver:
            token-uri: "************"
```

WebClient Configuration:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${rest.client.base-url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(@Qualifier("authorizedClientManager") final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager) {

        final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction clientExchangeFilterFunction = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(manager);
        clientExchangeFilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("******");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(this.baseUrl)
                .filter(clientExchangeFilterFunction)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                                         ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();

        final AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
 
}
```

I'm trying to successfully submit a request. But I am getting client_id error even though I have done all the configurations

Comment: Are you using the correct registration id (which is *myserver* in your case) here ?clientExchangeFilterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("******");

Comment: yes, I'm sure about that.